# Проблема с отправкой multipart/form-data скриптом php

Tags: php, fileupload

Пытаюсь передать изображение с удалённого сервера в контроллер для дальнейшей обработки.

```
    $url_image = 'http://vpoltave.info/uploads/ab/e977e56d31c874a1780528411755e2-bigimg.png';

    $image = file_get_contents($url_image);

    $mime_type = getimagesize($url_image)['mime'];

    $file_name = basename($url_image);
    $boundary = '--------------------------' . md5(microtime(true));
    $eol = '\r\n';

    $url = SITE_URL . '/upload/post-photo';

    $file_content = '--' . $boundary . $eol .
        'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="' . $file_name . '"' . $eol .
        'Content-Type: ' . $mime_type . $eol . $eol .
        //'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' . $eol . $eol .
        $image . $eol;

    $file_content .= '--' . $boundary . '--' . $eol;

    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create([
        'http' => [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' . $boundary,
            'content' => $file_content
        ]
    ]));

    var_dump($response); exit;
```

На данный момент в контроллере заглушка:

```
var_dump($_FILES); exit;
```

Заголовки запроса:

```
{
    "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------50fdc74116a157d67cdcd07aaf7dbf29",
    "User-Agent":"PHP (mysite.com), hosted by www.ukraine.com.ua",
    "Content-Length":"471222",
    "Connection":"close",
    "Geoip-Country-Code":"UA",
    "X-Real-Ip":"xx.xxx.xxx.xx",
    "Host":"mysite.com"
}
```

Но в $response всегда возвращается пустой массив. Подскажите чего не хватает... Почему массив $_FILES является пустым?

Comment: Я думаю стоит curl использовать.

Comment: Я рассматривал этот вариант, но там успеха тоже не достиг. Наверное что-то упускаю в заголовках или кодировке, хотя сравнивая с файлом отправленным через форму html, файл отправлен именно в таком виде. base64 тоже пробовал. Данный метод, на мой взгляд, выглядит проще, чем curl. Поэтому пока продолжаю копать в этом направлении.

Comment: Покажите как curl'ом пытаетесь?

Comment: К сожалению, откатить код до того момента не получится. Я перезатёр тот код этим.

Comment: Зря придёться вместе разбираться. Ща найду что нибудь

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/curl-file-upload вроде проще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хитрая ошибка. Не сразу обратил внимание.

Все у вас отлично, только в одной мелочи ошиблись - в кавычках.

Для `\r\n` следует использовать двойные кавычки, так как именно в них PHP распознает [управляющие последовательности](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double):

```
$eol = "\r\n";
```

Но можно и переписать код полностью, **используя CURL**. Приведенный пример только что протестировал у себя. Мне не очень нравится создание временного файла, возможно, есть выход и без него. Но работает как нужно и в таком виде.

```
$url_image = 'http://vpoltave.info/uploads/ab/e977e56d31c874a1780528411755e2-bigimg.png';
$url = 'http://192.168.1.3/file.php';

$ext = explode('.', $url_image);
$ext = array_pop($ext);

$tmpFileName = md5(time().$url_image).'.'.$ext;

$content = file_get_contents($url_image);
file_put_contents($tmpFileName, $content);

$post = array('file' => '@'.realpath($tmpFileName));
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

unlink($tmpFileName);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Тут комплексная проблема...

Comment: @Naumov да ладно, не вижу ему смысла переписывать код, если достаточно поправить кавычки. Если, конечно, он не планирует этот код потом апгрейдить, переиспользовать и расширять. Не красиво? Согласен. Но работает. А, чаще всего, только это и требуется.

Comment: ДА! Код заработал. Благодарю! Приходила такая мысль, но показалось нелогичным и откинул этот момент даже не протестировав))

Comment: Дело в том что лучше делать сразу правильно, а не править кастыли, к сожаления если надо получить инфу лучше будет `file_get_contents` если вам нужно что то отправить, лучше `curl` так как он автоматом вам всё раставит в соответствие со стандартами RFC. в общем не стоит изобретать велосипед.

Comment: @Naumov по больше части, я с вами согласен. В своей работе я придерживаюсь идеологии "сразу делать правильно". Но с другой стороны, я следую принципу "зачем делать лишнюю работу". Если код работает и работает стабильно - это правильный код. Он мог бы быть лучше, да. И короче. Но если у текущего варианта нет конкретных проблем - он годен. Хочу добавить, что все сказанное относится скорее к ситуации, когда нет готового варианта "правильного" кода и над ним нужно работать. В текущей ситуации, когда готовый код предоставлен, не вижу смысла выбирать "велосипедный" вариант с `file_get_contents`.

Comment: Создание временного файла - это именно то чего и добивался, так как контроллер уже написан для обработки файлов пришедших из html формы. Мне необходима была имитация этого, чтобы обработка была идентична и не плодить других контроллеров.